# Is it possible to have Facebook Comments post to my Facebook Page wall?

Tags: comments, facebook-page, facebook-comments

I have comments on the footer of each of my wallpaper pages:

http://www.socwall.com/desktop-wallpaper/30688/422-by-unknown-artist/

I'd like comments to post to my Facebook Page's wall:

http://www.facebook.com/SocWall

Is this possible?

Comment: To me I feel conceptually it does not really do what the comment box is for. The Facebook page's wall is for you to post updates to your users and the comment box is obviously for commenting. Your fans may not be interested in what is being commented on. I may be wrong but just my $0.02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but it will require some coding. Here are the basic steps:

1. Include the [Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) on your site and [subscribe to the comment.create](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) Javascript event that is fired whenever someone posts a comment.
2. Auth your users for your site and app (again using the JS SDK) and ensure you request the `publish_stream`, `user_likes` and `publish_actions` permissions.
3. When you get those permissions from the user, perform an FB.api call to /USERID/likes and check whether your Page ID is included in those list of likes.
4. If it is there, then once the event in step 1 is triggered you can then do a POST on the API to PAGEID/feed with `message` parameter included. This will post the comment to your Page's feed.

A couple of other things to bear in mind:

- If the user is **not** a fan of your page, you won't be able to do step 4.
- You **must** make it clear to the users that posting a comment will also post to your Page. If you do not tell them, this will put your app in violation of [Facebook Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) but more importantly, it'll break user trust and they might report your app.

Comment: Quick question, will these comments be posted as by the user or by the Facebook page.

Comment: They will appear as the user, they will only appear as the Page when you use a Page Access Token